# Python e Access

Tags: python, conexão

Ajuda por favor, minha classe não conecta no Access de jeito nenhum..
Estou usando: PyCharm, win10 (x64), office  2007 e 2016, python 3.6(x86). 
Desde já agradeço a atenção.
segue exemplo da classe:

```
class Banco(object):
def __init__(self):
    conStr = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=D:\BDFone\AgMesaIB.mdb"
    conxn = pyodbc.connect(conStr)
    self.cursor = conxn.cursor()


class Cadastro(object):

def __init__(self, controle="", nome="", nome2="", email="", telefone=""):
    self.info = {}
    self.cod = controle
    self.nome = nome
    self.nome2 = nome2
    self.email = email
    self.telefone = telefone

def selectCad(self, pnome):

    banco = Banco()
    try:
        c = banco.cursor()
        c.execute("select * from Geral WHERE Primeiro_nome='" + pnome + "'")

        for linha in c:
            self.cod = linha[0]
            self.nome = linha[1]
            self.nome2 = linha[2]
            self.email = linha[3]
            self.telefone = linha[4]
        c.close()

        return "Busca feita com sucesso!"
    except:
        return "Ocorreu um erro na busca do Cadastro"
```

Comment: Como sabe que ele não conecta?

Comment: Porque retorna o erro da except "Ocorreu um erro na busca do Cadastro"

Comment: Então você pode, ao invés de usar apenas `except`, fazer `except Exception as e` e colocar `return e`, assim você terá **exatamente** a mensagem de erro e não uma genérica que não te informa nada sobre o erro.

Comment: Segue sua orientação e funcionou. exibiu o seguinte erro:  'pyodbc.Cursor' object is not callabe

Answer (score 1):

Inicie verificando se você tem o driver do Access instalado:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Verificando se o driver está instalado"""
import pyodbc

print([x for x in pyodbc.drivers() if x.startswith('Microsoft Access Driver')])
```

O print acima deverá retornar algo semelhante a:

`['Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)']`

Caso seja retornada uma lista vazia `[]` você terá que instalar o diver:

**Driver Access 2010**:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255

**Driver Access 2016**:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Lembrando que:

- `*.accdb`: Formato utilizado pelo Access 2007 em diante.
- `*.mdb`: Formato utilizado pelo Access 97, Access 2000, Access 2002 ou Access 2003.

Arquivos `*.mdb` podem ter recursos limitados e não funcionar de forma adequada.

O código abaixo foi testado com um arquivo `*.accdb` e driver 2016:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Conectando no banco do MS Access"""
import pyodbc


class ConectarDB:
    def __init__(self):
        # Criando conexão.
        self.con = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
                                  r'DBQ=C:\Caminho\para\o\banco.accdb;')
        # Criando cursor.
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()

    def exibir_tabelas(self):
        for tabela in self.cur.tables(tableType='TABLE'):
            print(tabela.table_name)

    def consultar_registros(self):
        return self.cur.execute('SELECT * FROM NomeDaTabela').fetchall()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    banco = ConectarDB()
    banco.exibir_tabelas()
    # print(banco.consultar_registros())
```

Comment: Opa Renato, fiz o teste do drive e obtive sucesso > lista preenchida, mas ainda continua dando erro ao conectar conforme a excep que criei ao conectar.

Comment: Sim, o erro no seu código irá continuar porque você está chamando `c = banco.cursor()`, o que gera:

` 'pyodbc.Cursor' object is not callabe'`

Repare que você está chamando um método `Cursor()` que não existe na sua classe `Banco()`. Neste caso tente chamar assim:

`c = banco.cursor`

Sem os parênteses, neste caso você está instanciando a variável `cursor` que pertence a classe banco.

Já na consulta que você realizar:

`c.execute("select * from Geral WHERE Primeiro_nome='" + pnome + "'")`

Tente algo como:

`c.execute("select * from Geral WHERE Primeiro_nome=%s" % pnome)`

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente Renato, não havia me dado conta sobre a pseudo função cursor().  So vou frisar que a query em SQL gerou erro: parametros insuficientes, daí coloquei a que eu havia informado anteriormente e funcionou. Muito obrigado!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Não entendo muito de Acces e nem de python, mas consegui fazer com que meu código (simples) conectasse ao SqLite3, criando suas tabelas e colunas. Não sei se vai ajudar, mas, pelo sim pelo não... Código está embaixo:

```
import sqlite3
```

import time
import datetime

connection = sqlite3.connect('IMDC_DB.db')
c = connection.cursor()

def create_table():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dados_alunos (name text, idade integer,\
              numero text,materia text, cpf text, email text, data text)')

create_table()

def dataentry():

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO dados_alunos (name, idade, numero, materia, cpf, email, data)VALUES \
          (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', (nome_aluno, idade_aluno, numero_aluno,\
                             materia_aluno, cpf_aluno, email_aluno, date))

connection.commit()
```

print("Bem vindo(a) ao primeiro teste do Sistem do IMDC usando Banco de Dados!")
op_menu_aluno = 1
while op_menu_aluno != 0:
    print("=========")
    print("MENU IMDC")
    print("=========")
    print("[1] CADASTRAR ALUNO")
    print("[0] SAIR")
    op_menu_aluno = int(input())

```
if op_menu_aluno == 1:
    nome_aluno = input("Digite o nome do aluno(a): ")
    idade_aluno = int(input("Digite a idade do aluno(a): "))
    numero_aluno = input("Digite o telefone do aluno(a): ")
    materia_aluno = input("Digite a(s) matérias(s) que o aluno quer se matricular: ")
    cpf_aluno = input("Digite o CPF do aluno(a): ")
    email_aluno = input("Digite o Email do aluno(a): ")
    date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time.time())).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    dataentry()
elif op_menu_aluno == 0:
    print("Tchau")
else:
    print("Opção inválida")
```